# SPRQL reading data from a nested Array

Tags: sparql

i am trying to read a data from a dataset that has a list in it. here is an exmaple of it :

```
{
   "accessKey": "aabc0240-ec8a-4bd5",
        "accessList": [
          {
            "type": "intrusion",
            "source": "192.168.1.2"
          },
          {
            "type": "intrusion",
            "source": "192.168.1.12"
          },
   ],
}
```

trying to get the accessList using the accessKey (directly for testing only, the goal is to get the access list for every key) would result in something like this when selecting the list : "t5123". trying to access attributes like "type" or source results in nothing.

i tried using `rdf:type:intrusion` but that didn't work either.

This is an example of the query i am running :

```
SELECT ?accessList ?accessKey where {
    BIND(<aabc0240-ec8a-4bd5> as ?accessKey .
    ?logEvent prefix:accessKey ?accessKey .
    ?logEvent prefix:accessList ?accessList .
}
```

that would return accessList as a string like "t512". I tried the following afterwards

```
SELECT ?accessList ?accessKey where {
    BIND(<aabc0240-ec8a-4bd5> as ?accessKey .
    ?logEvent prefix:accessKey ?accessKey .
    ?logEvent prefix:accessList ?accessList .
    ?accessList rdf:type:intrusion ?source .
}
```

this doesn't return anything.

I admit i am new to sparql but i think this can be a prefix issue, but i don't know how to be sure of that.

Comment: your example is JSON, SPARQL is for RDF - it remains unclear how you you load the data into which SPARQL engine? So what is the point of SPARQL here? Where is the proper RDF data and where is your SPARQL query?

Comment: And what is `rdf:type:intrusion` for a syntax? I mean, in RDF there is a built-in property `rdf:type` - but is just use as the predicate of an RDF triple, thus, it should be used as predicate of a SPARQL triple pattern. You still have to define subject and object of the triple (pattern)

Comment: @UninformedUser please check my edit. The JSON is just to show the hierarchy of the data

Comment: still hard to judge based on non RDF data, but: `?accessList rdf:type:intrusion ?source .` is clearly weird, if the type is given, you should set it as object: `?accessList rdf:type :intrusion .` - and getting the source would be `?accessList prefix:source ?source .`